# How can I create an Azure CosmosDB Serverless using Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cosmosdb, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I've been trying to create the serverless offer of the cosmosdb database using Terraform, but haven't been able to do so.

After reading Microsoft's documentations and the Azurerm terraform registry documentations, I could code this resource:

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "resume-challenge-cosmosdb" {
name                      = var.cosmosdb-name
  location                  = var.region
  resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.cloud-resume-rg.name
  offer_type                = "Standard"
  kind                      = "GlobalDocumentDB"
  enable_automatic_failover = false
  enable_free_tier          = true
  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level       = "BoundedStaleness"
    max_interval_in_seconds = 300
    max_staleness_prefix    = 100000
  }
  geo_location {
    location          = "brazilsouth"
    failover_priority = 0
  }
}
```

but it creates the regular version of the cosmosdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a CosmosDB account serverless using the AzureRM Terraform provider you need to enable the `EnableServerless` capability on the `azurerm_cosmosdb_account`.  To do this you must add a `capabilities` block with `name = "EnableServerless"`.  Applying this to your above example would look like so:

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "resume-challenge-cosmosdb" {
name                      = var.cosmosdb-name
  location                  = var.region
  resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.cloud-resume-rg.name
  offer_type                = "Standard"
  kind                      = "GlobalDocumentDB"
  enable_automatic_failover = false
  enable_free_tier          = true
  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level       = "BoundedStaleness"
    max_interval_in_seconds = 300
    max_staleness_prefix    = 100000
  }
  geo_location {
    location          = "brazilsouth"
    failover_priority = 0
  }
  capabilities {
    name = "EnableServerless"
  }
}
```

I found this by searching for the word "serverless" on the [azurerm_cosmosdb_account](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cosmosdb_account) resource docs.

Comment: The serverless is the pay-as-you-go pricing option, does the "offer_type = Standard" interfires in the cost?

Comment: How does it interfere with the cost?  Not sure :)  I'd say your best bet is to provision a CosmosDB account using the above Terraform, and also provision a serverless CosmosDB account manually in the Azure Portal, and then compare the resulting JSON ARM template of the two.

Comment: I think it won't interfire in the costs. After creating, I went to the azure portal and saw the database is in serverless mode. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please accept my answer if it's solved your problem :)